# how to query unrelated tables without UNION, JOIN or multiple selection

Tags: mysql, sql

My issue is that I would like to query several different columns from 2 different tables, it is for a search feature where I want the results to show a mix of categories and products in the array.

Correct me if Im wrong, but I cant use `JOIN` because the tables are not related in any way.

I cant use `UNION` because there is no consistency in the amount of columns I want choose from per table.

And I tried simply selecting the combination of columns from the combination of tables but that multiplies everything. However Ill show you the code for the last option as perhaps there is a way of tweaking it to get it to work...

```
SELECT pd.product_id, pd.name, pd.meta_keyword, pd.description, cd.category_id,
  cd.name AS 'category_name'
FROM oc_product_description AS pd, oc_category_description AS cd 
WHERE pd.name LIKE '%$word%'
  OR cd.name LIKE '%$word%';
```

This returns the entire list of `oc_category_description` category_name values for every successful hit of `pd.name` whereas I ONLY want successful results of either the product name or the category name.

Comment: Please show example table contents and the desired results. You probably CAN use a UNION, you just need to add extra empty columns to one of them to get them consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `UNION`, you have to add all columns from the various tables and `NULL` values in the columns that are not supplied in other tables:

```
SELECT pd.product_id,                      -- pd columns
       pd.name , 
       pd.meta_keyword, 
       pd.description,

       NULL AS category_id,                -- cd columns
       NULL AS category_name
   FROM oc_product_description as pd 
   WHERE pd.name LIKE '%$word%' 

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, 
       NULL, 
       NULL, 
       NULL,

       cd.category_id , 
       cd.name AS category_name
   FROM oc_category_description as cd 
   WHERE cd.name LIKE '%$word%' ;
```